# How? Deformation

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bezier-curves

I need to incrementally push the vertices of the gear sideways, so that the start of the 'C' shaped gear is 5.5mm lower than the end of the gear.

Some kind of path/curve deform seems like the obvious solution, but nothing I have done works. Most methods either rely on having a flat/linear object to start with, and/or horribly distort the object in axes where I want no change.

Suggestions?

[image: Deform the Gear to be like the Curve]

Comment: If you want your model to follow a curve then you should model it straight.

Comment: The entire point is that I cannot model it straight. I need to deform an existing  round object.

Comment: if I got it right, you could try using another simple shape, subdivided enough, to create a snapping reference, then snap vertices (probably in groups) of the current gear to the reference points of the other simple shape. Or, create a "base" gear unit, and duplivert it along another reference curved linerar shape. A lot of manual work, in either way, of course...

Comment: or, even a "base" gear unit, then an array + curve modifier.... it could work

Comment: *sigh* I may need to do some snapping, as you suggest. However surely there is a simpler way to modify the object as-is. It's been many years since I last used blnder, but I find it difficult to believe that such a straight-forward operation seems so obscure that nobody knows how to do it....and inconceivable that blender 'cannot' do it.

Answer (score 1):

This (simplified) is just to give a better idea about the array+curve modifier method described above in comments:

[image]

Comment: The gear is a very specifically designed object. As in: it's an actual mechanical design that really functions as a gear that meshes with a worm drive. So although the obvious methods of rebuilding it from simple primitives may look useful... they totally aren't. I actually need to be able to deform the existing object.. I'm fairly surprised that there hasn't been a straight forward way to do this suggested yet.

Comment: This method still perfectly works for your case, I upvote anyway. Forget the *Array* part, just recycle the *Curve* modifier part that yields the deformation. Make sure you have a "cut" in your gear to it will actually split at that end and follow the spiraled curve.

Comment: Unfortunately it's really just a simplification and workaround, but doesn't answer the broader question I wanted answered, which was how to do this particular category of relatively simple deformation. I have a feeling some form of linear vertex influence attached to either end of the C is the answer, but nothing Iv'e tried works, and everything seems ludicrously overwrought for what should be a relatively basic function. Maybe what I really need is a proficiency with python.